# Injecting javascript thourgh <img>-tag

Tags: javascript, html, image, javascript-injection

I would like to know if it is possible to inject some javascript code through an img-tag. The scenario is that one sets up a html-page like this

```
<img src="anotherdomain.com/someimage.jpg" />
```

Anotherdomain is my domain. Is it possible to redirect the call for /someimage.jpg to another file containing som javascript code that is executed when the image is requested?

Comment: Not sure why this was downvoted. It is a reasonable question and not one that the answer could be easily found by an Internet search.

Comment: It's a good question, seeing as IE has a history of obeying the Content-Types that servers send, no matter what they are. It seems this is no longer the case, fortunately.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The browser should not make an attempt to execute code received via an `<img>` tag as JavaScript.  The script would be delivered to the browser, but in its place would be a broken image that could not be displayed.

Browsers will only execute scripts received in a `<script>` tag or `onclick,onmouseover,onmouseout,etc...` attributes as a basic security principle

Comment: so the only "fun" thing you can do is to redirect it to another image?

Comment: @MathiasBak Pretty much - or send a file that is very big, eating the client's (and origin server's) bandwidth.

Answer (score 2):

no, all major browser will not accept javascript code at this point

Answer (score 1):

No.  The problem (if you want to call it that) is that the URL in question is interpreted as image data, not as a JS script.  So regardless of what it is or how it's redirected, it's not going to get evaluated as JS.

Note: <script> tags work cross-domain, so you should probably just use that.